# Minimum number of streets

Tags: combinatorics

> Let's call a street a road from one intersection to another.
>
> In the city, at the same time, due to repairs, no more than 7 streets
> are blocked for traffic. What is the smallest number of streets in a
> city so that, during any repair work, a courier can deliver an order
> from a restaurant located at an intersection to an office located at
> another intersection?
>
> It is known that there is no route from a restaurant to an office that
> runs along less than 8 streets. The courier moves only along the
> streets, the courier cannot drive along the blocked street.

What ot read to answer this? First question where I don't where to start.

Comment: intersection of what?

Comment: This is a graph where streets are edges and locations are vertices.  The distance from the restaurant to an office is at least 8.  I think we are missing information, such as how many locations are there or can every location be reached from every other location. Terms you can search for are $paths$ in a $connected$ graph.

Comment: @user136920 (You can use asterisks for italic. Also double asterisks for bold)